# puppet apply 'could not find class'

Tags: puppet, puppet-enterprise

This is a pretty simple problem, and I have read a number of suggested solutions, but I still can't get puppet apply to import the git::config class. Here is my file setup:

I import the git module via nodes.pp:

```
#/etc/puppet/manifests/nodes.pp
node default {
}
include git
```

site.pp imports nodes.pp:

```
#/etc/puppet/manifests/site.pp
import 'nodes.pp'
```

The git module is defined as follows:

```
#/etc/puppet/modules/git/manifests/init.pp
class git {
    include git::install
    include git::config
}
class git::install{
    package {'git': => present }
}
```

and the config file:

```
#/etc/puppet/modules/git/manifests/config.pp
define git::config{
    [some code here]
}
```

When I run puppet apply, puppet does not find the git::config class:

```
sudo puppet apply --modulepath=/etc/puppet/modules /etc/puppet/manifests/site.pp
Error: Could not find class git::config for xxxx on node xxxx.
```

The original module was puppetlabs-git (same folder structure), but I have recreated the error using the simplified file structure (above).

**Update 1**

Typo above, the git config.pp and init.pp are in folder /modules/git/manifests and the config.pp file reads 'define git::config'

Comment: Is it a typo that there is no `class` keyword in the `git::config` file?

Comment: pp file need be put under `git/manifests` folder, not directly under git folder.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You cannot call `include` on `git::config`. `git::config` is a [defined type](https://docs.puppetlabs.com/learning/definedtypes.html), not a [class](https://docs.puppetlabs.com/puppet/latest/reference/lang_classes.html). The syntax to use a `defined type` is as follows:

```
git::config { 'the_name_var':
  param1 => 'foo',
  param2 => 'bar'
}
```

Hope this helps

Answer (score 5):

Your puppet code structure is wrong. You need move your pp file to manifests folders.

```
/etc/puppet/modules/git/init.pp
/etc/puppet/modules/git/config.pp
```

to

```
/etc/puppet/modules/git/manifests/init.pp
/etc/puppet/modules/git/manifests/config.pp
```